# Are innerHTML elements visible to jQuery functions?

Tags: functions, jquery, ajax

For example, on my admin page i.e. dashboard side:

```
//This is hidden until search results come back
//which will be inserted as innerHTML within #searchResults
<div id="hideShow">
<h2>Search Results</h2>
<div id="searchResults"></div>
</div>

//This is visible all the time
<div><form>some fields etc</form><button id="buttonSearch"></div>
```

And then:

```
//javascript file start
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    jQuery("#hideShow").hide();

    jQuery("#buttonSearch").click(function()
    {
        jQuery.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function(response)
        {
            //response is json array, I loop through and it becomes:

           ( contents of response :
        <tr><td><a id="edit">Edit</a> | <a onclick="haha()">Delete</a></td></tr> )

            document.getElementById("searchResults").innerHTML = response;
            jQuery("#hideShow").show();
        }
    }
}

jQuery("#edit").click(function()
{
        alert('inside edit');
}   

function haha()
{
    alert('im haha');
}

//javascript file end
```

I had to type up a simplified version of what I have so ignore spelling errors etc, it is a working code. The problem is that both

```
<a id="edit">Edit</a> | <a onclick="haha()">Delete</a>
```

are output as innerHTML and regular JS function haha works, whereas "edit" doesn't. I tried various locations within and outside of innerHTML, whenever it is outside of innerHTML jQuery "edit" works, but not when inside.

I can find a workaround, but was it supposed to work or whenever you output something as innerHTML it is sort of invisible to jQuery? Because innerHMTL is not visible when I do View Page Source.

Comment: Why not use `jQuery('#searchResults').html(response);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when `("#edit").click(` is called, the element "#edit" doesn't exist so the `.click(` cannot be attached

## solution 1

you call `click(` juste after `.innerHTML = response`

## solution 2

use delegated event like that : 
`$("body").on("click", "#edit", function () {...`

Comment: Thanks, I will try that, I have some idea about a workaround, but that's what I don't understand, why it doesn't exist? It is visible on the page, regular Javascript can see all elements, but not jQuery.

Comment: it's because `jQuery("#edit").click(function()` is done at the page load and long time after, the element `a id=edit` is created so click doesn't apply because it's too late. but `live(` works in this case because it apply to future elements

Comment: `.live()` has been deprecated for a very long time (since jquery 1.7). `.on()` should be used instead.

Comment: @MattvanAndel thank you, I don't have seen that. I edit my answer